# Azure APIM & oAuth 2.0 with Multiple Clients

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I am finding it hard to understand how I can differentiate multiple client applications using oAuth 2.0.

Using APIM I mapped my backend webservice to Azure API Gateway Service URL. I have configured Oauth 2.0 with grant type as client credentials because its a service to service integration.

In Oauth registration, I have mapped my client and backend app Id's with secret keys - (OauthSample1.0).
It doesnot have the provision to configure multiple clients for the same backend service.

And, in my API, i can add only one Oauth reference - (OauthSample1.0). Even if i would go ahead and create multiple Oauth 2.0 references for different clients, technically it cannot work with the API configuration.

This means I can have my API validate only one specified client using one oAuth 2.0 reference.

If I want my API to be accessed by different partners / Client applications, my understanding is that I would need to create different Clients in Azure AD. But unfortunately not able to design the solution here.

Comment: were you able to resolve this and add multiple client IDs to APIM?

Answer (score 1):

The [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) for protecting your API using OAuth 2.0 covers the steps required in detail.

To summarize, the steps are

1. Register an application to represent the API

   - This app is setup to [expose an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)
2. Register separate applications to represent each of your client applications

   - These apps would also have a secret generated for the client credential flow
   - These apps would have been [granted access to the exposed API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#grant-permissions-in-azure-ad)
3. Setup a [Validate JWT policy to pre-authorize requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests).

Your clients would have to get the token using the client credentials flow before making the requests.

Also, if your clients are services that directly access the APIs, then you could setup [app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) that show up as Application Permissions instead of Delegated Persmissions.

Comment: Even though multiple client apps are granted access for the exposed API but on the APIM side where we set up the O-Auth 2.0, there is no provision to pass multiple client IDs and secrets as required by @battech . Any means to implement the following scenario ?

Comment: Only clients granted access will be able to fetch an access token for the backend API. So validating it against the `aud` claim should suffice.

Comment: Correct *aud* can be used to validate the JWT token where it will be the application ID of the server app which will represent the API.  But on steps 12 and 13 of the following [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#enable-oauth-20-user-authorization-in-the-developer-console) we don't have an option to configure the O-Auth using multiple client Id and secret. It will be just a single client Id and secret of a client app. How to  grant the access to multiple client apps ? Can you provide any related article ?

Comment: Those steps are specific to the developer portal which acts as a client application in this scenario. You'd store the client ID and client secret in secure storage (like KeyVault) for each of your client.

Comment: Also, if your clients are services that directly access the APIs, then you could setup [app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) that show up as Application Permissions instead of Delegated Persmissions.

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT I am still confused on how we can add multiple Client ID and Secerets in APIM (in the oAuth and Client setup) for leveraging oAuth 2.0. Cause we have multiple Clients consuming the APIM hosted APIs and no way to add multiple clientIDs in APIM.